# Synchronize Document Between Local Drive and SharePoint 2013 Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sync, download

Is there a way for users to download a copy of a SharePoint Excel 2010 file, save it locally, and have the local copy update with all future changes made to the SharePoint document? Or does anyone have any other suggestions for a single source of truth between files downloaded from SharePoint and the files saved on SharePoint? 
Additionally, we do not use OneDrive or Office 365.

Comment: what is your sharepoint version?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 and Office 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SharePoint 2013, you can use One Drive for business to share your libraries to locally. It is automatically update the SharePoint as well as Locally once a change has been made.

You can read this blog for more understanding.[How to sync your SharePoint 2013 document libraries with OneDrive for Business](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-sync-your-sharepoint-2013-document-libraries-with-onedrive-for-business)

If you dont have the one drive for bussines then you can think about the Mapping the Drive.

- You can map your SharePoint library locally to your computer. this way you can manage the files easily. [check this for more information.](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/09/06/map-sharepoint-libraries-with-local-file-drive-a-step-by-step-guide/)

Comment: The issue now is we do not use One Drive for business.

Comment: I am trying to implement a solution that is passed to a group of users that are part of workflows. It seems this solution would require each user to go and map that drive. Another problem with this drive mapping solution is each document in the library has a subset of pertinent users. It seems the users would see every document in the mapped drive instead of just the files that they have permissions to like it does in the SharePoint library.

Comment: these are the limitation for this type of workaround, i think best solution in this case is if you able to get the onedrive, or may be you have to look for 3rd party option